# Google Cloud Platform blocking BatchRequest request - Java

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to wait until a BatchJob (BatchRequest objecT) in GCP is completed?
I.g. you can do it with a normal Job:

final Job job = createJob(jobId, projectId, datasetId, tableId, destinationBucket);

```
    service.jobs().insert(projectId, job).execute();

    final Get request = service.jobs().get(projectId, jobId);
    JobStatus response;

    while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(500); // improve this sleep policy
        response = request.execute().getStatus();
        if (response.getState().equals("DONE") || response.getState().equals("FAILED"))
            break;
    }
```

Something like the above code works fine. The problem with batchRequest is that the jobRequest.execute() method does not return a Response object.

When you execute it, the batch request returns after it has initialised all the jobs specified in its queue but it does not wait until all of them are really finished. Indeed your execute() method returns but you can have failing jobs later on (i.g. error due to quota issue, schema issues etc.) and I can't notify the client on time with the right information.

You can just check the status of all the created jobs in the web UI with the job history button from the BigQuery view, you can't return error message to a client.

Any idea with that?

Comment: What library are you using to access BiqQuery? [Job](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.4.0/apidocs/com/google/cloud/bigquery/Job.html) in [google-cloud](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.4.0/index.html) will let you wait on results.

Comment: com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all:[1.6.0, 2.0.0) is the library, not others are used but from the Google standard ones. The porblem is: I know Job can wait on results. BatchRequest can't so I don't wont ended up writing a Future<Callable<Job>> framework that wait until all jobs get done.